# DART Editor, "Dead code" statement

Tags: dart

I'm trying to toggle my menu upon clicking menuicon (defined as #lines) in my code below.

In execution, everything is fine, I  mean, once I run the code in DARTIUM it works as I want, the menu is toggled upon the click.

but in Dart editor, I got the error msg in the attached pic, am I doing something wrong in my code?

```
void main() {
  .... 
   var menuToggle =querySelector('#lines')
      ..onClick.listen((e)=>fonixMenu.hidden=true ? !fonixMenu.hidden : false);  
  ....
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's telling you that the `false` in your code will never be reached, because the `true` causes the first part of the expression to be returned.

You can simplify it to:

```dart
onClick.listen((e) => fonixMenu.hidden = !fonixMenu.hidden);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actually wanted to do was

```dart
void main() {
  .... 
   var menuToggle =querySelector('#lines')
      ..onClick.listen((e) => fonixMenu.hidden = fonixMenu.hidden == true ?  = false : fonixMenu.hidden = true);  
                                            // ^ 2nd =
  ....
 }
```

but Danny's solution is more elegant when you ensure that `fonixMenu.hidden` is never `null` because

```dart
var x = null;
var Y = !x
```

causes an exception:

```dart
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool' of 'boolean expression'.
```

A simple null-safe variant

```dart
   var menuToggle =querySelector('#lines')
      ..onClick.listen((e) => fonixMenu.hidden = fonixMenu.hidden == true ? false : true);
```

Comment: I think you're missing an assignment too? ` (e)=> fonixMenu.hidden = fonixMenu.hidden  == true ? !fonixMenu.hidden : false); `